# Unable to use a helper function in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

My Laravel version is **4.2.6**.

My PHP version is **5.4.16**.

I am trying to use a custom helper function `errors_for()`, but I am getting this error:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqPpS.jpg
```

Why is that? i don't get it. I am loading the file, because my file `helpers.php` is located in `app/Acme/helpers.php` as you can see here:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaO4f.jpg
```

and contains:

```
<?php

function errors_for($attribute, $errors) 
{
    return $errors->first($attribute, '<span class="error">:message</span>');
}
```

And I am calling it in my view like this:

```
{{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
{{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ errors_for('email', $errors) }}
```

In my `composer.json` I have this:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "file": ["app/Acme/helpers.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "app/Acme"
        }
    },
```

I already have run `composer dump-autoload` with the response `Generating autoload files`

And I have tried to restart the WAMP server, but it didn't help.

Comment: Go to bootstrap/start.php and add this: include 'app/Acme/helpers.php';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"file"` in your *composer.json* should be named `"files"`.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Comment: Damn, seems to be the case ;D. Thank you.